# Java Minimax Algorithm Issue

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am creating a game with java. The program works perfectly when I have the computer pick from an arraylist of legal moves, but when I tried writing a minimax algorithm it created a problem. I kept all the same code that works fine, but just added the following line:

```
System.out.println("Minimax Value: " + c.minimax(game, 2, true));
```

which generates an error. When it is set to 1 it doesn't crash the program, but messes with the game score, but when it is at 2 (as it is now) the program crashes. I will insert the code for the minimax method below and would appreciate help figuring out what is wrong with it. Also, the algorithm returns the value of the sequence of moves, but how do I get it to store the actual move that is played?

```
public double minimax(GamePosition position, int depth, boolean maximizingPlayer){
    EvaluateGameState whoWonGame = new EvaluateGameState();
    Value val = new Value();
    GameEnded gameDone = new GameEnded();

    if(depth == 0){
        return val.getValue(position);
    }
    if(gameDone.gameOver(position)){
        return whoWonGame.whoWon(position);
    }

    if(maximizingPlayer){
        GenerateMoves gm = new GenerateMoves();
        ArrayList<Integer> legalMoves = gm.getLegalMoves(position);

        double bestValue = -10000;

        GamePosition node = position;
        for(int i=0; i<legalMoves.size(); i++){
            ApplyMove apply = new ApplyMove();
            node = apply.makeMove(node, legalMoves.get(i));
            double value = minimax(node, depth-1, false);
            bestValue = Math.max(bestValue, value);
        }
        return bestValue;
    } else {
        GenerateMoves gm = new GenerateMoves();
        ArrayList<Integer> legalMoves = gm.getLegalMoves(position);

        double bestValue = 10000;

        GamePosition node = position;
        for(int i=0; i<legalMoves.size(); i++){
            ApplyMove apply = new ApplyMove();
            node = apply.makeMove(node, legalMoves.get(i));
            double value = minimax(node, depth-1, true);
            bestValue = Math.min(bestValue, value);
        }
        return bestValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: It woul be helpful if you add the  error ,or if you attach the stacktrace

Comment: @RO_engineer When I have depth at two or higher I get the following problem: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:495)
 at fiftyfiftyfixed.ApplyMove.makeMove(ApplyMove.java:24)
 at fiftyfiftyfixed.ComputerStrategy.minimax(ComputerStrategy.java:36)
 at fiftyfiftyfixed.ComputerStrategy.minimax(ComputerStrategy.java:51)
 at fiftyfiftyfixed.PlayerVsComputer.gameFlow(PlayerVsComputer.java:18)
 at fiftyfiftyfixed.FiftyFiftyFixed.main(FiftyFiftyFixed.java:10)

Comment: @RO_engineer Although even when the depth is at 1 and the program doesn't crash it still messes with the game total and score even though the fields in GamePosition are private and all I am doing with the minimax results currently is printing the result.

Comment: @user7638746 if you read the stacktrace from bottom to top, you'll find the methods that were called eventually resulting in the crash. The last line of code mentioned of your source code is fiftyfiftyfixed.ApplyMove.makeMove(ApplyMove.java:24) (after that is all java.util stuff). So... that's where you'll want to look for the cause of your issues. You didn't include the code for your ApplyMove class in the OP, so can't help you any further than this